# Como realizo una sentencia con dos condiciones en una funcion

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

[image: Tengo esta sentencia en la cual quiero obtener unicamentes los productos que cumplan con esas condiciones sin embargo no me toma en cuenta la segunda condicion que sea mayor que 0 el stock, la parte del estatus si lo hace pero el stock no.]

[image: Tengo esos datos en la tabla y esa consulta directamente si lo esta haciendo bien sin embargo al colocarla en codeigniter 4 no esta funcionando.]

Alguien sabe cual es el error?

Tengo esta sentencia en la cual quiero obtener unicamente los productos que cumplan con esas condiciones sin embargo no me toma en cuenta la segunda condicion que sea mayor que 0 el stock, la parte del estatus si lo hace pero el stock no.

Tengo esos datos en la tabla y esa consulta directamente si lo esta haciendo bien sin embargo al colocarla en codeigniter 4 no esta funcionando.

Answer (score 0):

Hay varias formas de hacerlo, según la [documentación](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#where).

Puedes llamar varias veces a `where`, por ejemplo:

```
->where('estatus_producto', 1);
->where('stock >', 0);
```

Puedes también crear un array asociativo:

```
$params = array('estatus_producto' => 1, 'stock >' => 0);
```

Y luego:

```
->where($params);
```

O (método no recomendado) crear una cadena con toda la consulta, por ejemplo:

```
$str = "estatus_producto = 1 AND stock > 0";
```

Y luego:

```
->where($str);
```

Si optas por esta última posibilidad, debes escapar los valores para prevenir *inyección SQL*.